# Asynchronous requests with gcloud command line utility?

Tags: asynchronous, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcutil

`gcutil` had a  --[no]synchronous_mode option, allowing a command to return immediately after posting a request.

I can't find a similar feature in `gcloud compute`, as `gcutil` is being deprecated. That's particularly unhelpful for scripts doing disk snapshots, for example.

Is there a way to issue asynchronous requests with `gcloud compute`?

Answer (score 1):

In its current version, gcloud offers the *--async* flag with those subcommands that allow asynchronous operations, such as

$ gcloud sql instances create

Please find the complete reference to the gcloud CLI utility at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/

Comment: My question was more specifically about gcloud compute, gcloud compute disks snapshot for example, does not support the --async flag.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sammy Villoldo's response, generically, you can always background a task with `&` (assuming you're running a Unixy shell and not cmd.exe or PowerShell).